# JSON Object Parse

Tags: json, parsing, object

[exercise question screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4fP0.png)

Not sure what's missing. The other discussion solutions seem too complicated compared to my homework question:

> Q:
>
> -The variable str_json has been assigned a string of a JSON object
>
> -Call the parse method, pass it str_json and assign the return value to variable jsonobj
>
> -Assign the property the_city to the variable v_the_city
>
> -Assign the property stateval to the variable v_stateval

```
var str_json = {'v_the_city':'the_city','v_stateval':'stateval'};
var jsonobj = JSON.parse(str_json);
```

> SyntaxError:
>
> the JSON dataJSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of
>
> SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier

Comment: Why are you parsing something that *isn't* a string? It's already JS, not JSON.

Comment: To be valid `str_json` should look more like this: `"{\"v_the_city\":\"the_city\",\"v_stateval\":\"stateval\"}"` if it is actually supposed to be a string...

Comment: @jonrsharpe not sure, so how should it look?

Comment: It should *be a string*, as shown by @War10ck

Comment: @War10ck That's the question in full, so i guess it shouldnt be a string

Answer (score 0):

`str_json` should be a JSON string, not an object.

The `JSON.parse()` method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string. An optional reviver function can be provided to perform a transformation on the resulting object before it is returned. Read more here, [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).
**Syntax:**

```
JSON.parse(text[, reviver])
```

**Parameters:**
text - The string to parse as JSON. See the JSON object for a description of JSON syntax.
reviver - [Optional] If a function, this prescribes how the value originally produced by parsing is transformed, before being returned.

Comment: I think that might be more than what I need, we haven't discussed the reviver option. Lets forget that I provided an answer. with the questions values listed how would you create this?

-The variable str_json has been assigned a string of a JSON object

-Call the parse method, pass it str_json and assign the return value to variable jsonobj

-Assign the property the_city to the variable v_the_city

-Assign the property stateval to the variable v_stateval

Comment: The answer just tells you the usage about `JSON.parse()` method which can receive a String text as parameter and a optional fuction. The point is that it would throw SyntaxError if you pass a wrong type parameter to it.

Comment: I deleted the snippet because I think that was confusing everyone. I'm supposed to build code following the exact instructions provided.

Comment: I added a screenshot of what the question looks like, I'm supposed to build from scratch using that.

Comment: got it up again, this is what I got from those instructions for the question.